# Asterisk PAMI how to find related events

Tags: php, asterisk

I have the following code:

```
$pamiClient = new ClientImpl($params);

$pamiClient->open();

$originateMsg = new OriginateAction('PJSIP/9090');
$originateMsg->setContext('from-internal');
$originateMsg->setPriority('1');
$originateMsg->setAsync(true);
$originateMsg->setCallerId('Test');
$originateMsg->setExtension('user phone');

$response = $pamiClient->send($originateMsg);

$pamiClient->close();
```

Response is returned:

```
"response": "Success",
"actionid": "1607830126.4974",
"message": "Originate successfully queued",
"created": 1607830126
```

My task is to log all actions
Call started 9090 to user phone, ended 9090 to user phone, etc.

To do this, I listen to all the actions of the asterisk, but I do not know how to link the response received after the call and the event
You cannot connect by calleridnum since 9090 can call different numbers
How can i get the linkedid by actionid?

Example events:

```
array(17) {
["event"]=>
string(13) "HangupRequest"
["privilege"]=>
string(8) "call,all"
["channel"]=>
string(19) "PJSIP/9090-000007f5"
["channelstate"]=>
int(5)
["channelstatedesc"]=>
string(7) "Ringing"
["calleridnum"]=>
int(9090)
["calleridname"]=>
string(7) "Test"
["uniqueid"]=>
string(15) "1607830255.6102"
["linkedid"]=>
string(15) "1607830255.6102"
...
```

Comment: Those IDs are just timestamps, so not much help. The OriginateResponse event should be sent and include the channel, I think the channel would be the best way to tie events together.

Answer (score 1):

Every time when channel start you got NewChannel event. In that event you have uniqueid field, store it with callerid and other info you needed AND channelname.

Every time you have any action you have same uniqueid in it OR channel name. When you have child's channels like in queue you have linkedid=parent channel id.

There are also some masquerade events which change channel name etc etc.

Check FOP (flash operator panel) code. It really not trivial to do that via AMI, worth few years of development.